# mvc generate javascript inside an action

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently trying to figure out how to efficiently generate a javascript section for my view that will involve some json

eg:

```
var info = {
  "race":[
    { "name" : "finalPoll",
        "drivers": [
           { "id": 1, "driver": "d1" },{ "id": 2, "driver": "d2" },{ "id": 3, "driver": "d3" }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

That will need to be generated when the view is called. I didn't want to save it as a file as that will just complicate things. Inserting them to the aspx page would be the best way i can think of.

With that said, how do I properly process the data using an action?

Answer (score 0):

You could always store the JSON as a string in your Model and then write that to the page in your view.

Comment: @gdubs - Or adding it to your View Model (if you're using one).

Comment: I wasn't actually planning on using one since the main model will be able to handle it and it's an Edit action but I think this might work better.